# Inequality with a rational polynomial

Tags: number-theory, inequality, polynomials

Let $$P(x)=x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}\,x^{n-2}+a_{n-3}\,x^{n-3}+\cdots+a_0\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$$ be a monic rational polynomial of degree $n-1$.

I want to show that, for every set of $n$ distinct integers $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$, there exists $i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ such that 
$$\big|P(x_i)\big|\ge\frac{(n-1)!}{2^{n-1}}\,.$$

I don't know how approach this problem.

Note that the degree is $n-1$ yet there are $n$ integers.

Comment: What are $x_1,x_2,\dots$?

Comment: distinct integer numbers

Comment: Well, are the $x_i$s are given in advance? What about $P(x)$?

Comment: $$P(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$$

Comment: Is there any relation between the $x_i$ and, the $a_i$ and the polynomial, or are the $x_i$ arbitrary integers without any relation to the polynomial?

Comment: Just they are distinct.

Comment: @ downvoters: I think the question makes sense as it was given, or at least I don't see an obvious counterexample?

Comment: I reformulated the question. Can you please confirm or deny this is what you mean? // A problem with you question may be that it looked as if there was a mix up, while it was actually correct. Another is that there is not much motivation or context, but that's I think secondary in this case.

Comment: @ quid so thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is true for any monic polynomial $P(z)\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ of a given degree $n-1$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and for any pairwise distinct $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $x_i-x_j\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$.  Without loss of generality, we shall assume that $\text{Re}\left(x_1\right)<\text{Re}\left(x_2\right)<\ldots<\text{Re}\left(x_n\right)$.

We note from the Lagrange Interpolation Theorem that
$$P(z)=\sum_{i=1}^n\,P\left(x_i\right)\,\prod_{j\in[n]\setminus\{i\}}\,\left(\frac{z-x_j}{x_i-x_j}\right)\,,$$
where $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Since $P$ is monic, 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\,\frac{P\left(x_i\right)}{\prod_{j\in[n]\setminus\{i\}}\,\left(x_i-x_j\right)}=1\,.$$
Using the Triangle Inequality and the assumption that the $x_i$'s are mutually distinct with integral differences, we conclude that $$\prod_{j\in[n]\setminus\{i\}}\,\left|x_i-x_j\right|\geq (n-i)!\,(i-1)!$$ for all $i\in[n]$, and that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\,\binom{n-1}{i-1}\,\frac{\big|P\left(x_i\right)\big|}{(n-1)!}\geq 1\,.$$
I leave the rest to you.

> A final hint is that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\,\binom{n-1}{i-1}\,\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=1\,.$$  Note also that this bound is sharp by taking $x_i=i$ and $$P(i)=(-1)^{n-i}\,\frac{(n-1)!}{2^{n-1}}$$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: So much thanks  :)

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{(i-1)!(n-i)!}}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{i!(n-1-i)!}}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   n  \\
   i  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}}{(n-1)!}=\frac{{{2}^{n-1}}}{(n-1)!}$$

Comment: is above comment correct  ?

Comment: No, the second and the third expressions should be $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\,\frac{1}{i!\,(n-1-i)!}$ and $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\,\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\,\binom{n-1}{i}$, respectively.

Comment: yes it was a typo

Comment: Then, yes, apart from the typos, everything was correct.

Comment: should we suppose $M=\max\{|P(x_i)|, i=1,2,\cdots n\}$?

Comment: That's one way to do it.  An alternative way is to show a more general statement: if $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^n\,a_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^n\,b_i$, then there exists $i$ with $a_i\geq b_i$.

Comment: you rescue me , for $i=1,\cdots ,\infty$  "Thanks$_i$ "

Comment: I think you need to assume (wlog) that the x_i are ordered by their real parts to get the (n-i)!(i-1)! inequality.

Comment: @stewbasic  Yes, I do need that.  Thanks.  Edited now.